# PHP: Save as dialog with custom content

Tags: php, file, content-disposition, save-as

I have the following code:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=bookmark.adr");
readfile('bookmark.adr');
```

This makes a save-as popup where an user can save the bookmark.adr file. But I would like to custom generate the content of that file. How can I generate the content and let that file be popupped as save-as?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do `readfile()`.  Echo out whatever you want that file to contain instead.

Your `Content-Disposition` header is what will tell most browsers to prompt the user to save the file.

Comment: @Jordy, The source code of what page?  Your file will contain whatever you echo out.  If that's HTML, then that's what will be in the file.

Comment: Last question. What should the Content-type be for a .adr file?

Comment: @Jordy, I'm not familiar with `adr` files, but some quick Googling suggests `text/directory`.